# Twitter typeahead.js having trouble showing suggestions when data fetched from remote

Tags: django-templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I am having trouble displaying results as suggestions on entering text in input box.

```
<input type="text" id="search_country" class="form-control" placeholder="Add country">
```

Below is my typeahead code:

```
$('#search_country').typeahead({
    name: 'countries',
    valueKey: 'name',
    remote: {
        url: '/user/countries/%QUERY',
        filter: function (parsedResponse) {
            return parsedResponse;
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting json response in the below format:

```
[{"image": "india.jpeg", "name": "India"},
{"image": "germany.jpeg", "name": "Germany"}]
```

However the results are not showing up as suggestions below input box.

Rather in console I am finding an error similar to error given below:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '14771' in

```
[{"image": "india.jpeg", "name": "India"},
{"image": "germany.jpeg", "name": "Germany"}]
```

Where am I going wrong?
I want the result to contain a list of countries with each list item having image at left and name at right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [typeahead.js search from beginng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964740/typeahead-js-search-from-beginng)

Comment: check of the results of /user/countries/%QUERY realy equals the above cause the error is triggered when parsedResponse is not a valid datum according: The canonical form of a datum is an object with a value property and a tokens property.

Comment: Okay. So how do it customize the parsedResponse so that it should match the structure of datum?

Comment: yes, try that or try first without the filter()

Comment: Tried but getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `filter` is doing nothing, I would remove it.

Comment: It looks like it should work, are you sure you aren't returning a string that looks like JSON, as opposed to a JSON string?

Comment: I do get a response from django view bu along with is comes the error mentioned above.